# Trying to convert a varbinary(MAX) value in SQL to byte[] and displaying in an asp image control

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

The end goal will be to be able to select a company and all its details from the database using a webform, then update/create new entries. All this works, except with the Logo

The Logo is stored in a SQL database as varbinary(MAX), which is have pulled into C# and converted into byte[] in order to display it using an asp image controller.

Front end

```
<img src="" runat="server" id ="image" />
```

Pulling the Logo from the Database using a SqlDataReader

```
        public TemplateData(SqlDataReader dr)
    {
        initialiseData();
        if (dr.HasRows)
        {

            byte[] Logo = (byte[])dr["Logo"];

            //Logo = dr["Logo"].ToString();
            TemplateId = dr["TemplateId"].ToString();
            Comment = dr["Comment"].ToString();
            SchemeCode = dr["SchemeCode"].ToString();
            Version = dr["Version"].ToString();
        }
    }
```

Code behind

```
        protected void ddSchemeCode_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ddSchemeCode.SelectedIndex > 0)
        {
            // Existing Data to load from database
            TemplateData temp = DataClass.ReturnData(ddSchemeCode.SelectedItem.Text);
            if (temp != null)
            {
                txtVersion.Text = temp.Version;
                txtComment.Text = temp.Comment;
                txtSchemeCode.Text = temp.SchemeCode;
                txtTemplateId.Text = temp.TemplateId;
                image.Src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(temp.Logo);
            }

        }
```

The Error I receive is when a company is selected is "Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: inArray"

I've tried umpteen other ways of doing this and none of them seem to do the trick.
Any help is much appreciated, 
Cheers!

Comment: Could you verify the value of **dr["Logo"]** ?

Comment: It's a Column name in the database, taken from a SqlCommand `string sqlInstructionCstmID = "SELECT TOP(1) LetterTemplateCustomisationId, TemplateId, Logo, SchemeCode, Version, Comment FROM LetterTemplateCustomisation WHERE SchemeCode ='" + schemeCode +"'";`

Comment: At the very least, since the error mentions a parameter called `inArray`, you probably need to find a piece of code where that same name appears and show those bits also by [tag:edit]ing your question (Single lines of code are rarely helpful in a question because it's unlikely that you're isolated the problem down to the single line causing the problem - if you had, you probably wouldn't need to ask the question)

Comment: "inArray" doesn't appear anywhere in my code. Sorry for the lack of context, Edited.

Comment: Still can't see it anywhere in your code.

Comment: Exactly! I'm stumped!

Comment: Well isn't the error telling you that "inArray" NEEDS to be populated in your code?   That's what it's telling me.   The problem is probably in your DataClass.ReturnData method.   Which line of code does the error occur on?

Comment: No.   "InArray" is the name of a parameter that is expected by some stored procedure or function that you are calling.   And you are not providing the parameter that is expected.

Comment: It's highlighting `image.Src = "data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(temp.Logo);` as the problem.?

This was termed as a "quick alternative" so could be a bit dodge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524(v=vs.110).aspx), `inArray` is the parameter name for `Convert.ToBase64String(byte[])`. Therefore, `temp.Logo` must be `null`.

Answer (score 0):

image.Src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])dr["Logo"]);

Above code is working. We have to insert/update image to column Logo.
Ex:

```sql
update <table> 
    set Logo= (SELECT BulkColumn 
    FROM Openrowset( Bulk 'LogoPath...' , Single_Blob) as img)
```